# How set access rights in odoo?

Tags: odoo

Hi I want to create department wise access rights in HR module not employee wise.so in hr module we have department . i wanted to assign login to department . only belonging to that employees can only get assigned modules to that department

Thank You

Comment: you can try .csv file into this type of group

Comment: access_hr_department_user,hr.department.user,model_hr_department,base.group_hr_user,1,1,1,1

Comment: i dint get you . where i should go in odoo settings because i am very new to this

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create group for different department.
and give access rights of menus of associate department groups.

Answer (score 0):

In `security.xml` create separate group for each department. Now in `ir.model.access.csv` apply permissions for each group (department). Go to `settings->users` and `create a user` if you haven't already. Now edit the user under `access rights` you will see different groups that you have created. Add user to the desired group. All permissions of that group will be applied to the user.